# Is there a way to display webdriver instance on iframe site

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm stuck on how can I open the instance of webdriver on my html page using java.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); // Open the Application
```

the code below open the instance of driver chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start chrome browser, first download chromeDriver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) After that we need to specify this downloaded chromedriver and then start the driver instance

```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "\\downloaded driver path");

  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

  driver.get("http://URL here/");
```

Then as said need to switch to frame, so

```
   driver.switchTo().frame("iframe id or name");

    //or

    driver.switchTo().frame("index like 0, 1");

    //or

    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe"))); //iframe location

    //after work in frame is completed, then we need to switch back to default content

    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: Thanks for your reply, when I write   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();, a new session of chrome browser open. And what I want is to embed that session on my site that I'm developping in J2ee.

Comment: driver always create new session when it starts. So are you planning to add this session into j2ee project?